# Generating SQL query in R; removing back-slash from query

Tags: sql, r, paste

I am trying to update a SQL query in R in an automated way. I am using a repeat loop and within the loop I want the query to be updated with a new date to filter by. Here is my code:-

```
sqldate = as.Date("2021-06-01")


repeat{
  
  if(sqldate=="2021-06-20"){
    
    break
  }
  
  sql = paste0('SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = "', sqldate, '"')
  print(sql)
  
  sqldate = sqldate +1
  
  Sys.sleep(100)
}
```

But it gives me this output:-

```
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-01\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-02\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-03\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-04\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-05\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-06\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-07\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-08\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-09\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-10\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-11\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-12\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-13\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-14\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-15\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-16\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-17\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-18\""
[1] "SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = \"2021-06-19\""
```

The back-slashes are causing errors as it is not an appropriate SQL query. What can I do to force the `paste0()` function to leave out the back-slashes?

Comment: \" is not a part of the variable sql, it's just how R print escaped quotes. You can check with length(sql). Please post how the sql query fails.

Comment: Here is the error:- ```"HY000 35 [Cloudera][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '1' error message: 'Error while processing statement: FAILED``` ,(FYI I am using the ```RODBC``` library in R). the back-slash is not a part of the SQL statement but R is placing them there due to escaped quotes. I need to know how to remove the back-slashes

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example including your code using RODBC? As mentioned above R is not placing any escaped quotes, it just look like that in the printed output. You can check with length() or cat().

Comment: Your problem is that `"` is not a quotation in SQL terms. In most SQL databases (I believe the only exception I've come across is Snowflake) `"` is reserved for symbol names (such as table names and so forth) and one has to overwrite this in the database to avoid such behaviour. Use single quotes `'` instead.

Comment: Change your `paste0` to use single quotes as noted above: `sql = paste0("SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable = '", sqldate, "'")`

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. Consider using a date-range (one query) instead of multiple single-date queries.

   ```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM mockdataframe
   WHERE datevariable BETWEEN '2021-06-01' and '2021-06-20'
   ```

   If you need them each date in separate frames, then it is still far better/faster to run a single query and split after-the-fact:

   ```r
   dat <- sqlQuery(con, qry)
   datspl <- split(dat, dat$datevariable)
   ```
2. If you really must run each date individually, then I suggest `lapply` around a `seq`uence of dates.

   ```r
   dates <- seq.Date(as.Date('2021-06-01'), as.Date('2021-06-20'), by = "1 day")
   queries <- paste("SELECT * FROM mockdataframe WHERE datevariable =", sQuote(dates, FALSE))
   datspl <- lapply(queries, RODBC::sqlQuery, channel = myconn)
   ```

   Note that this is *not* executing "bound parameters" as mentioned in my note below.
3. You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

   The connection mechanisms between `DBI`/`odbc` and `RODBC` are fairly similar (same databases and connection options are supported). You might do this with bound parameters:

   ```r
   library(DBI)
   con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), server="..", uid="..", pwd="..") # args depend on your DBMS
   dat <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from mockdataframe where datevariable between ? and ?",
                     params = list(as.Date("2021-06-01"), as.Date("2021-06-20")))
   ```